# EF4 C# Poco Templates

Tags: entity-framework

I have installed EF4CSharpPocoTemplates.
Still I am not able to see POCO entity generator in my

Addnewitem->code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will show only if you use .NET 4.0

Comment: I was creating vb project. that is why i did't get that.